# React-card-flip, Map through data and flip one card at a time

Tags: reactjs

As a precursor I found two other posts with the same question, one with no answer and the other one does not have a sufficient answer as he is not mapping through data in the answer, here is the post [React-card-flip flips all cards on one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401363/react-card-flip-flips-all-cards-on-one-click).

I am using react-card-flip from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-flip, and trying to map through my ProjectData.json and return a card to be flipped for all my data. Everything works except for the fact that all the cards flip at the same time when any of them get hovered.

In my code you will find that I removed the button and onClick like you see in the react-card-flip npm website and replaced the front div with a onMouseEnter and the back div with a onMouseLeave, this is just to have the card animation work on hover instead of onClick.

Projects.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCardFlip from 'react-card-flip';
import Data from '../../ProjectData.json';
import './Projects.scss';


class Projects extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state = {
      isFlipped: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isFlipped: !prevState.isFlipped }));
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Projects">
      {Data.map(project => {
        return (
        <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
        <div onMouseEnter={this.handleClick} className="CardFront">
          <div >
            This is the fron of the card
              <h3>{project.title}</h3>
              <img src={project.gif} />
              <ul>
                <li>{project.html}</li>
                <li>{project.css}</li>
                <li>{project.javascript}</li>
                <li>{project.react}</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
 
        <div onMouseLeave={this.handleClick} className="CardBack">
          This is the back of the card.
        </div>
      </ReactCardFlip>
        )
      })}
      </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Projects
```

ProjectData.json

```
[
    {
        "title": "Movie Search app",
        "link": "",
        "html": "HTML",
        "css": "CSS",
        "javascript": "JavaScript",
        "react":"React",
        "api": "Axios",
        "gif": "https://media.giphy.com/media/YrSZQZTMsdT0qrOZOk/source.gif",
        "description": "A movie search application using MovieDB's API that displays movie information, conver art, aswell as Related Searches and Trending Searches."
    },
    {
        "title": "Movie Search app",
        "link": "",
        "html": "HTML",
        "css": "CSS",
        "javascript": "JavaScript",
        "react":"React",
        "api": "Axios",
        "gif": "https://media.giphy.com/media/YrSZQZTMsdT0qrOZOk/source.gif",
        "description": "A movie search application using MovieDB's API that displays movie information, conver art, aswell as Related Searches and Trending Searches."
    },
    {
        "title": "Movie Search app",
        "link": "",
        "html": "HTML",
        "css": "CSS",
        "javascript": "JavaScript",
        "react":"React",
        "api": "Axios",
        "gif": "https://media.giphy.com/media/YrSZQZTMsdT0qrOZOk/source.gif",
        "description": "A movie search application using MovieDB's API that displays movie information, conver art, aswell as Related Searches and Trending Searches."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactCardFlip from "react-card-flip";
import Data from "./data.json";

const CardStyle = {
  border: "1px solid black",
  padding: "20px",
  margin: "20px",
  width: "200px",
  height: "300px"
};

const Card = ({ project }) => {
  const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = React.useState(false);
  // console.log(project);
  return (
    <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
      <div
        style={CardStyle}
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsFlipped((prev) => !prev)}
        className="CardFront"
      >
        <div>
          This is the fron of the card
          <h3>{project.title}</h3>
          <img width="200" src={project.gif} alt="" />
          <ul>
            <li>{project.html}</li>
            <li>{project.css}</li>
            <li>{project.javascript}</li>
            <li>{project.react}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={CardStyle}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsFlipped((prev) => !prev)}
        className="CardBack"
      >
        This is the back of the card.
      </div>
    </ReactCardFlip>
  );
};

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: "50%" }} className="Projects">
      {Data.map((item, index) => (
        <Card project={item} key={`card-${index}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

[image: Edit kind-jackson-jzp9u]